PrimeReact TreeTable size prop not working, even in official StackBlitz example
I'm trying to use the size prop in PrimeReact's TreeTable component, but it's not having any effect. The TypeScript type indicates that the size prop should accept a number, but when I pass a value like size={10}, there's no noticeable difference in the table.
I even tried this in the official Prime React TreeTable Basic example example on StackBlitz, using the basic usage demo, but still no effect. Here's my code based on that example:
import { TreeTable } from 'primereact/treetable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
export default function BasicDemo() {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    NodeService.getTreeTableNodes().then((data) => setNodes(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <TreeTable size={10} value={nodes} tableStyle={{ minWidth: '100rem' }}>
        <Column field="name" header="Name" expander></Column>
        <Column field="size" header="Size"></Column>
        <Column field="type" header="Type"></Column>
      </TreeTable>
    </div>
  );
}


